# Why does Chocolatey fail to pack a ~2GB self-contained package?

Tags: windows, chocolatey, cpack

I would like to build a self-contained "app.nupkg" package from "app.nuspec" file using `cpack` command. Here is the directory tree of my application:

```
C:\CHOCO_REPO\APP
│   app.nuspec
│
├───bin
│       dist
│       Setup.exe
│
└───tools
        chocolateyinstall.ps1
        chocolateyuninstall.ps1
```

The dist file (size ~2G) is actually the program. When I try to run:

```
cpack app.nupgk
```

I get:

```
bin\dist
Cannot access a closed stream
```

with debug option:

```
cpack app.nuspec -d
```

I get:

```
Attempting to build package from 'app.nuspec'.
bin\dist
Attempting to delete  file "C:\choco_repo\APP\app.nupkg".
Chocolatey had an error occur:
System.ObjectDisposedException: Can not access a closed Stream.
at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.EnsureNotDisposed()
at MS.Internal.IO.Packaging.CompressStream.Flush()
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.FlushExposedStreams()
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOLocalFileBlock.UpdateReferences(Boolean closingFlag)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveContainer(Boolean closingFlag)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOBlockManager.SaveStream(ZipIOLocalFileBlock blockRequestingFlush, Boolean closingFlag)
at MS.Internal.IO.Zip.ZipIOModeEnforcingStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.IO.Stream.Close()
at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.Close()
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoClose(PackagePart p)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.DoOperationOnEachPart(PartOperation operation)
at System.IO.Packaging.Package.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
at NuGet.PackageBuilder.Save(Stream stream)
at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.nuget.NugetPack.BuildPackage(PackageBuilder builder, IFileSystem fileSystem, String outputPath)
at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.services.NugetService.pack_run(ChocolateyConfiguration config)
at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.GenericRunner.run(ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container, Boolean isConsole, Action`1 parseArgs)
at chocolatey.infrastructure.app.runners.ConsoleApplication.run(String[] args, ChocolateyConfiguration config, Container container)
at chocolatey.console.Program.Main(String[] args)
Exiting with 1
```

Any help? thank you

Answer (score 0):

It could be the size. NuGet and .NET have some limitations around the size of what can go into the package.

It could be just Choco, but I doubt it since it is built as AnyCPU which means x64 when in 64-bit.

I've seen some folks do some ingenious things to take a 6GB iso and split it into multiple packages that are dependencies of a master package.

Comment: Actually the "dist" file has 2.7GB size. Are there reference/links you are aware of that can point me in the right direction to try to solve this problem?